Delete duplicate object in array due to addToSet
Thank you in advance for your time.
Recently we found that a new developer implemented addToSet versus set when updating info in a collection.  As a result, we now have duplicate objects in our documents due to addToSet seeing the order of objects as unique event thought the data may be the same.  Is it possible to remove duplicates, leaving the bottom entry as the valid object?  We have only been able to remove all and add back, but since these relations are linked in other documents, we would prefer to simply remove the older entries to preserve the links in other docs.
example document excerpt in collection - note some docs have multiple additions of the HOME basis, so we would like to ONLY keep the last (latest reference)
{
  "_id":"doc_123456789",
  "relations": [
    {
      "groupId": "59fab2dd-a3eb-4bb0-8fb5-1a2c4d0209c7",
      "basis": "HOME",
      "memberRole": "OWNER"
    },
    {
      "groupId": "ccd882a9-c3e1-4ba9-bdd7-13928fd9dd56",
      "basis": "FAMILY",
      "memberRole": "PARENT"
    },
    {
      "basis": "HOME",
      "groupId": "59fab2dd-a3eb-4bb0-8fb5-1a2c4d0209c7",
      "memberRole": "OWNER"
    },
    {
      "groupId": "634012ca-5d91-4691-ae1b-1890613cd5e2",
      "basis": "HOME",
      "memberRole": "OWNER"
    }
  ],
...

addToSet behavior - https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#value-to-add-is-a-document

Some ambiguities here: 1. How do you define duplicate? by the field basis? 2. How do you define latest? by the order in the array? If the answers to above is "yes", you could be looking for something like this

Duplicate is based on the basis field, correct.  and yes, latest is the last entry in the arrays order.   Rather than linking to a speciic doc, by _id, we would need to loop thru all docs in the entir collection, if possible (thought would be using a match where relations counts are > 1)

The $addToSet might be misused that it use the whole object for dupe check. As long as any field in the object is different, they won't be regarded as dupe, and hence causing duplicate array entries.
You may want to use below update code to conditionally add new entries to the relations array.
db.collection.update({
  "_id": "doc_123456789"
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "relations": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "entryToInsert": {
              "basis": "HOME",
              "groupId": "c",
              "memberRole": "OWNER"
            }
          },
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": "$relations",
                  "as": "r",
                  "cond": {
                    "$ne": [
                      "$$r.basis",
                      "$$entryToInsert.basis"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              [
                "$$entryToInsert"
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground
So, for the clean-up, you can do the followings in the aggregation pipeline:

(optional) $match the docs that you want to update
$unwind the relations array
$group by $_id and $basis to select only the last doc by $last
$group again by $_id and $push the last docs in each basis back into the array of relations
$merge to update back to the collection and persist the changes

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$relations"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "basis": "$relations.basis"
      },
      "lastDoc": {
        "$last": "$relations"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id._id",
      "relations": {
        "$push": "$lastDoc"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id"
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

This was a great start, but I was unaware that $merge does not exists in version 4.0 so I add a for loop to go through the results and update each.

@mike That makes sense to use forEach for such an old MongoDB version. If the update volume is large, you may want to use bulk operation to minimize db roundtrips too.
